# StreamWriter inserindo linhas em branco

Tags: c#, stream

Estou implementando o download de um arquivo em ofx, estou gerando o string e em seguida adiciono a um **StreamWriter**, porém se eu acrescentar linha por linha ou adicionar o string inteiro de uma vez sem quebra de linhas, ele cria um arquivo com várias linhas no final em branco, depois do conteúdo da string, segue o código:

```
string ofx = metodoQueRetornaString();
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8, 512);
file.Write(ofx.Replace("\n", file.NewLine));
file.Flush();
file.Close();
```

A string ofx retorna com algo do tipo:

`OFXHEADER:100\n<OFX>\n<INFORMAÇÕES DO OFX>\n</OFX>`

Deveria criar um arquivo com o conteúdo:

```
OFXHEADER:100
<OFX>
<INFORMAÇÕES DO OFX>
</OFX>
```

Está criando um arquivo com esse conteúdo:

```
OFXHEADER:100
<OFX>
<INFORMAÇÕES DO OFX>
</OFX>






`
```

Obs: coloquei esses acentos apenas para representar as linhas vazias.

Comment: Não deu pra entender qual é o problema. Tem como editar e colocar um exemplo **simples** de como deveria ser o arquivo e como ele está ficando? E também, como está a `string` com o conteúdo.

Comment: Olha, acabei de criar uma aplicação com este código da sua pergunta e tudo funciona normalmente. Minha dica é verificar o retorno deste método pra ver se ele não adiciona quebras de linha no final da string.

Comment: ok, vou verificar, obrigado

Comment: @jbueno consegui, mandei um array de bytes direto, sem passar pelo stream, acho q era bug do memoryStream ou do StreamWriter